# How to set text_field required attribute false to submit the form using Ruby on Rails

Tags: javascript, html, ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to submit a form with a looped `text_field`. But whenever I click the submit button, nothing is happening. The VIP name `text_field` is displaying whenever the user click the VIP discount from the discount dropdown. For each VIP ticket, there's a field for VIP name. The `text_field` is required. I'm trying to submit it by clicking the Purchase button. **Maybe the required field on the hidden text_Field is taking effect that's why the form can't submit yet**. I tried to implement the javascript `.removeAttribute("required")` and the `.required = false;` whenever the `text_field` is hidden but it didn't work as well. What's your thought?

[image]

```rb
<%= f.fields_for :movie_tickets do |mtf| %>
  <div class="row text-center">
    <label>============================ <%= "TICKET " + @count.to_s %> =============================</label> <br> <br>
    <b> SEAT NO: <%=mtf.object.seat.name%> | ORIGINAL PRICE: <label class="label_original_prices"><%= number_to_currency mtf.object.net_price, unit:'' %></label> | DISCOUNTED PRICE: <label class="label_discounted_prices" id="pricediscount<%=@count%>">No Discount</label> </b> <br> <br>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-md-3">
      <label>DISCOUNT :</label>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-9">
      <%= mtf.select :discount_id, options_from_collection_for_select(discounts, :id,:name),{include_blank:true}, class:"form-control", id:"discount"+@count.to_s, onchange:"getDisc(this)" %>
    </div>
  </div>

  <br><br>

  <div class="form-group" style="display: none;" id="divVIP<%=@count%>">
    <div class="col-md-3">
      <label>VIP NAME :</label>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-9">
      <%= mtf.text_field :vip_name , placeholder: "Type VIP name here...",class: "form-control", required: true %>
    </div>
  </div>
  <% @count += 1 %>
<% end %>

<script type="text/javascript">
  if(getValueDiscount == "9") {
    document.getElementById('divVIP' + count).style.display = "block";
  }else {
    document.getElementById('divVIP' + count).style.display = "none";
  }
</script>
```

Comment: Please, add the form definition to the snippet.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `required: true` or set it to `false` in the below line:

```
<%= mtf.text_field :vip_name , placeholder: "Type VIP name here...",class: "form-control", required: true %>
```